# Validate on update - Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

when I try to update a record in the database my model validations are not executed. The function updates the info but does not validate it. This is the update function

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {

const id = req.params.id;

const updateUser = {
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirm: req.body.confirm,
    email: req.body.email,
}


User.update(updateUser, { where: { id: id } })
    .then(user => {
        delete updateUser.password; delete updateUser.confirm;
        res.status(200).json({ msg: "Updated!", user: updateUser })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (err instanceof ValidationError) {
            let msgs = err.errors.map(error => error.message)
            res.status(422).json(msgs)
        }
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Ups...' + err));
```

}

```
    const { Model } = require('sequelize');

    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    class User extends Model {

      static associate(models) {}

    };

    User.init({

      firstName: {
       type: DataTypes.STRING,
       allowNull: false,
       validate: {
        notNull: {
         msg: "Not Null"
        },
        isAlpha: {
         args: true,
         msg: "Alpha"
        },
       notEmpty: {
        args: true,
        msg: "Not Empty"
      },
      len: {
        args: [3, 255],
        msg: "Length error"
      },
    }
  },

  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
    hooks: {
     afterCreate(record) {
      delete record.dataValues.id;
      delete record.dataValues.password;
      delete record.dataValues.confirm;
    },
  }
});
return User;
};
```

sequelize manual: Model validators allow you to specify format/content/inheritance validations for each attribute of the model. Validations are automatically run on create, update and save